# How to get CodeIgnitor 3 to autoload when coding tests?

Tags: php, codeigniter, testing

I'm new to CI and am struggling to get my head around it.

I'm familiar with Laravel and Symfony and I'm finding it very difficult to test CI code.

I'm considering the service locator pattern to try and work around the dependency injection limitations, but right now I'm struggling with autoloading.

Let's say that I have a model like this:

```
<?php

class FooModel extends CI_Model
{        
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('alertnotificationservice');
    }
}
```

I want to write a test that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Test\AlertNotification;

// extends TestCase and offers reflection helper methods
use Test\TestBase;

class FooModelTest extends TestBase
{

    public function test_my_method()
    {
        $objectUnderTest = new \FooModel();
    }
}
```

When I run my test I get the error `Error: Class 'CI_Model' not found`.

I'm using CodeIgnitor 3.1.2 and it doesn't use composer or include the phpunit.xml.dist file that the version 4 manual refers to.

What is the "proper" way to get the autoloading to happen so that I can run my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a satisfactory way to do this.  I ended up creating a `bootstrap.php` file that I include from phpunit.xml.dist

It looks something like this:

```
<?php

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
// this is a copy of the default index.php shipped with CodeIgnitor
// The system and application_folder variables are replaced
// Also, in this version we do not bootstrap the framework and rather include our own version below
require('loader.php');
// this is a modified version of system/core/CodeIgniter.php
// they do bootstrapping, routing, and dispatching in one place
// so we can't use the whole file because dispatching fails when running tests
require('framework.php');

// set up the test environment database connection
putenv('DATABASE_HOST=localhost');
putenv('DATABASE_USER=user');
putenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD=password');
putenv('DATABASE=control_panel');

// CI uses a singleton approach and creates an instance of a child of this class during dispatch
// We need to make sure that the singleton holder is populated
$controller = new CI_Controller();
```

The `framework.php` is a stripped down version of that CodeIgnitor file where I've removed the routing and dispatch logic.  I've put the files up as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/andybeak/168edc127f9dad45785168bc64fedc88)

The crux of the loading in CI seems to exist in `system/core/Controller.php` and the controller is intended to be something that lets "so that CI can run as one big super object".  The `load_class` function (declared in `system/core/Common.php`) is responsible for hunting down and loading the class files.

I should also include my `composer.json` file.  I'm using this for testing (CI 3.1.12 does not use composer)

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Test\\": "tests/"
        },
        "classmap": ["application/", "system/"]
    }
}
```

I would really like to avoid loading absolutely everything, and would like to be able to mock out bits and pieces, but I'm not optimistic that CodeIgnitor lends itself to this.

Anyway, this approach at least lets me boot my app.  There has to be a better way of doing this, I can't believe that the framework could be so popular if it's so hard to test properly.